# Detect if another app is running

Tags: android, activity-manager, activity-monitor

Is it possible on Android to detect if another app is running? I need to trigger some action in my app when a Map application (like Waze or Google Maps) is running.

Comment: Detect an app running as in detect while your app is running if a map app is in the background? Or do you mean automatically launch your app when a map app is ran? The former you should be able to accomplish with something along the lines of @Kasra's answer, however, I'm not sure if the latter is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ActivityManager class:

```
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
    {
        Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
    }
```

Please be aware that [this capability was deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) in API level-21.

An alternative could be `getRunningAppProcesses()` method of `ActivityManager`.

Comment: getRunningAppProcesses only returns own package