# Detecting if another app is collecting high-fidelity GPS information while my app is in the background? (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gps, location

Is there a way for me to tell whether my app's user currently has a navigation app or another app running in the foreground that collects high-fidelity GPS information while my app is in the background?

I am interested in mimicking this behavior in iOS [Detect if another app is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652076/detect-if-another-app-is-running)

I understand that detecting which app is in the foreground is in general not possible for iOS, but I am curious if there is a way to detect whether a navigation app is in the foreground by checking for high fidelity GPS data collection.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You can't do that in iOS